# regular expressions in java

Tags: java, regex, tokenize, split

I have a problem where I need to tokenize my string (using java code) so that it is split into a String array. Each token in this array should be either a word, number or dimensions of the form (23 x 34 x 56, etc.) I tried to code this as:

```
String[] split_text = text.split("\\s | (\\d{3},)*\\d{3}([.]\\d)* x (\\d{3},)*\\d{3}([.]\\d)* | \\d*([.]\\d)* x \\d*([.]\\d)*");
```

But, this is giving a syntax error. Can anyone please tell me how I can do this using regular expressions, and whether there is a problem in the way I have expressed the regular expression in java?

Comment: can you also post sample input and expected output.

Comment: Just a tip: paste your regular expression in http://www.strfriend.com/ to visualize it graphically. Helps me a lot from time to time.

Comment: @Rodrigo: That link is supremely awesome; +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match any pair of numbers with dots or commas and an x in the middle you could do something like this:

```
(\d*(?:[.,]\d+)* x \d*(?:[.,]\d+)*)
```

or for pairs and triples:

```
(\d*(?:[.,]\d+)*(?: x \d*(?:[.,]\d+)*){1,2})
```

so maybe thats your expression:

```
((?:\d*(?:[.,]\d+)*(?: x \d*(?:[.,]\d+)*){1,2})|\s|\w+)
```

See here: http://rubular.com/r/snAiI7GMT7 - a great site for testing.

You might want to replace the `\w` with `\p{L}` to cover all unicode words in java.

Comment: thanks! it just needs to be modified to incorporate the additional constraint that the comma has to be after every third digit only.

Answer (score 0):

The [**String.split**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) returns an **array** of Strings.

Make `split_text` an array:

```
String[] split_text = ...
      ^^
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo earlier... split_text is an array.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a syntax error in your regex, but there are a few problems:

- Whitespace *is*  significant in a regex, so don't put spaces in the regex where you're not expecting them in the string.
- Use `\.` to match a literal dot.
- `(\d{3},)*\d{3}([.]\\d)*` will match `123,456,789.1.1.1.1` but not `1,234.67`. Is that really what you intended?
- `<number> x <number>` will only match pairs of numbers, not triplets as in your example.

I think it's best if you update your specifications a little. What *exactly* do you/don't you want to match. Give a few examples. Think of corner cases (is a leading zero allowed? can it be dropped as in `.12`? How about `1.4E-45` and so on)...

Comment: thanks a lot... yeah, I want to match whitespaces and dimensions of the form 23.345 x 25.455 x 9032.232 or 234,232 x 234,2343 (which include a whitespace). A leading zero is allowed and also can be dropped in the case of  .12 . So, its basically the most general case.

Comment: also, don't wanna match 1.4E-45

Comment: So the thousands separator is optional? Do you want the regex to perform a check whether it's in the correct place, or can it be assumed that it will be, so no validation is required?

Comment: Also, what's your definition of "word"? English? Is punctuation allowed (`it's`)? How about foreign words with special characters (`naïve`)? I take it you want to match dimensions first, and only match a single number if it's indeed single? You really need to write a spec of what you want, otherwise all efforts to write a regex are pointless.

Comment: the thousands separator is optional,  the commas for the thousands place will be in the correct position so no validation is required.

Comment: punctuations and foreign words are allowed. Yes, I want to match a dimension first and match a single number if it is indeed single. Also, after splitting the text into a String array, I want to be able to keep track of the beginning and end indices of each token in the original text.

Comment: you can assume that 'text' here is a sentence, since a sentence detector has been run on it earlier.